# Flattr API v2 Get Subscriptions

Tags: flattr

I have some problems to read the users subscriptions.

As I can read in the api documentation, I have to send the following request:

GET https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/user/subscriptions

After that, I receive a response, but with weired content:

> [{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"thing"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/3951323"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"https://flattr.com/thing/3951323"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":3951323},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"http://www.gramocast.net/flattr"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":1},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":1},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"gramocast"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":""},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":[]},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"en_GB"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":"software"},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":1425413536},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":{"type":"user","resource":"https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/users/gramocast","link":"https://flattr.com/profile/gramocast","id":"jy3lmA","username":"gramocast"}},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":0},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":""},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":true},{"type":"subscription","active":false,"created_at":null,"started_at":0,"thing":true}]'

I have one active subscription to gramocast.
Is this a bug in the flattr api or am I doin' something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That weird response was the result of a bug in the Flattr API.
I deployed a patch yesterday so it should work as intended now.

I'm sorry it took so long to fix it. :(

// Leif